# python code to get the files outside the current working directory

Tags: python

using python code how can i get the files outside the current working directory

am working with `e:\names\test.py directory`

```
dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dirpath prints e:\names
```

in `e:\images`

how can i get the path  `e:\images\imh.png` from  the file `test.py`
Am hardcode the above path in `test.py`,how can i set the relative path inside `test.py` file

Comment: I think this may work... `"..\images\imh.png"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0]` to get the parent directory.

Then, you can use:

```
a=os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0]
os.listdir(a)
```

for listing the contents of the parent directory

Also, this works too:-

```
os.listdir(os.pardir)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0] + '/directory_name')
```

Comment: Please improve your post by explaining what you are doing and why. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for some hints on how to write good answers. (Your answer is probably working, but you're not explaining it. Also, why insert at index 1 and not 0?)